# Can you color an adjacent cell in gt table in r?

Tags: r, gt

a1 and b1 are colored based on their values. I would like a2 to be the same color as a1 and b2 the same color as b1. Is this possible?

[image: gt table with colored cells]

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
library(viridis)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(exp = (LETTERS[1:5]),
           a1 = sample(x = 1:20, size  = 5),
           a2 = sample(x = 1:10, size  = 5),
           b1 = sample(x = 1:20, size  = 5),
           b2 = sample(x = 1:10, size  = 5))

df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
        columns = c(a1,b1),
        colors = scales::col_numeric(
          palette = viridis(20, direction = 1, option ="D"), #color from viridis package
          domain = NULL)
      )
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first intuition was to grab the colors for `a1` and `b1` in the `gt` object:

- But it was not possible to find them there, so

Next I created a vector of the colors like

```
#install.packages("colourvalues")
library(colourvalues)
colors <- color_values(df$a1)
```

and wanted to apply it to `colors` parameter in `data_color` for column `a2`

- But this is not possible according to this issue https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/633.

On the same site @jthomasmock provided a solution with an own html before `gt`.

- But this raised problems according to the text font on dark background, which

I could solve with the help of @stefan here: [How to use INLINE HTML to make text white on dark background automatically after setting background from palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728687/how-to-use-inline-html-to-make-text-white-on-dark-background-automatically-after/70728727#70728727)

```
#install.packages("prismatic")
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(gt)
library(viridis)
library(prismatic)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    color = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = viridis(20, direction = 1, option ="D"), #color from viridis package
      domain = NULL)(a1),
    a1 = glue::glue(
      '<span style=\"display: inline-block; direction: ltr; border-radius: 5px; padding-right: 2px;',
      'color: {prismatic::best_contrast(color, c("white", "black"))}; background-color: {color}; width: 100%\"> {a1} </span>'
      ),
    a1 = map(a1, ~gt::html(as.character(.x))),
    a2 = glue::glue(
      '<span style=\"display: inline-block; direction: ltr; border-radius: 5px; padding-right: 2px;',
      'color: {prismatic::best_contrast(color, c("white", "black"))}; background-color: {color}; width: 100%\"> {a2} </span>'
    ),
    a2 = map(a2, ~gt::html(as.character(.x))),
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    color = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = viridis(20, direction = 1, option ="D"), #color from viridis package
      domain = NULL)(b1),
    b1 = glue::glue(
      '<span style=\"display: inline-block; direction: ltr; border-radius: 5px; padding-right: 2px;',
      'color: {prismatic::best_contrast(color, c("white", "black"))}; background-color: {color}; width: 100%\"> {b1} </span>'
      ),
    b1 = map(b1, ~gt::html(as.character(.x))),
    b2 = glue::glue(
      '<span style=\"display: inline-block; direction: ltr; border-radius: 5px; padding-right: 2px;',
      'color: {prismatic::best_contrast(color, c("white", "black"))};background-color: {color}; width: 100%\"> {b2} </span>'
      ),
    b2 = map(b2, ~gt::html(as.character(.x))),
  ) %>%
  select(-color) %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]

Comment: This is way more complicated than I imagined so thanks for taking the time @TarJae