# How to use INLINE HTML to make text white on dark background automatically after setting background from palette

Tags: html, css, r

This question is somehow related but not depending to this [Can you color an adjacent cell in gt table in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727702/can-you-color-an-adjacent-cell-in-gt-table-in-r):

**I am explicitly looking** for the modification of the `<span style=\...</span>` part of my code!

I have this example dataset with colors of the background of `mpg` column depending on the values applied with html.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(gt)
library(viridis)

head(mtcars[,1:2]) %>% 
  mutate(
    color = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = viridis(20, direction = 1, option ="D"), #color from viridis package
      domain = NULL)(mpg),
    mpg = glue::glue('<span style=\"display: inline-block; direction: ltr; border-radius: 5px; padding-right: 2px; background-color: {color}; width: 100%\"> {mpg} </span>'),
    mpg = map(mpg, ~gt::html(as.character(.x)))
  ) %>% 
  select(-color) %>% 
  gt()
```

which gives:

[image]

**I would like to have** the text in `mpg` column in white color conditional to dark background **coded in the inline html part** of my code e.g. before transforming to an `gt` object.

**While this works: This is not what I am looking for!**

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
library(viridis)

head(mtcars[,1:2]) %>%  
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = c(mpg),
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = viridis(20, direction = 1, option ="D"), #color from viridis package
      domain = NULL)
  )
```

gives:

[image]

**I have tried so far:** adding `color:white` to inline html

```
head(mtcars[,1:2]) %>% 
  mutate(
    color = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = viridis(20, direction = 1, option ="D"), #color from viridis package
      domain = NULL)(mpg),
    mpg = glue::glue('<span style=\"display: inline-block; direction: ltr; color:white; border-radius: 5px; padding-right: 2px; background-color: {color}; width: 100%\"> {mpg} </span>'),
    mpg = map(mpg, ~gt::html(as.character(.x)))
  ) %>% 
  select(-color) %>% 
  gt()
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be `prismatic::best_contrast`. By default it will not use pure `white` so we have to set the colors:

```r
prismatic::best_contrast("red", c("white", "black"))
#> [1] "black"

prismatic::best_contrast("purple", c("white", "black"))
#> [1] "white"
```

This could be added easily to your `glue` string to set font color based on the background color:

```
head(mtcars[, 1:2]) %>%
  mutate(
    color = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = viridis(20, direction = 1, option = "D"), # color from viridis package
      domain = NULL
    )(mpg),
    mpg = glue::glue(
      '<span style=\"display: inline-block; direction: ltr; border-radius: 5px; padding-right: 2px;',
      'color: {prismatic::best_contrast(color, c("white", "black"))}; background-color: {color}; width: 100%\"> {mpg} </span>'
    ),
    mpg = map(mpg, ~ gt::html(as.character(.x)))
  ) %>%
  select(-color) %>%
  gt()
```

[image]

Comment: Your are the king!

Comment: Haha. Not me. It's the developer of the `prismatic` package. I just made an edit. Actually `prismatic::best_contrast` does not use a pure "white" for the light font color.

Comment: You helped me to solve this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727702/can-you-color-an-adjacent-cell-in-gt-table-in-r/70728817#70728817>. Many thanks!